# Adding style sheet from Lightning Design system to visual force

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system, hyperlink

I'm trying to link my custom Lightning design system (Lightningdesignsystem_new) to visualforce page. The MIME type of Lightningdesignsystem_new is application/x-zip-compressed. This was working fine but my sandbox was updated to summer 2018 release, since then my style sheet broke.

I want to refer my style sheet from Lightningdesignsystem_new in visual force page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" extensions="ActionCtrl" showQuickActionVfHeader="true" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" lightningStylesheets="true" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:slds />
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!FollowUpEvent != null}">
        <apex:form id="form" styleClass="slds-form">
            <apex:pageblock >    
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <style>
                        input.combobox, select
                        {                
                        border: 1px solid #d8dde6;
                        border-radius: .25rem;
                        width: 100%;
                        transition: border .1s linear,background-color .1s linear;
                        display: inline-block;
                        padding: 0 1rem 0 .75rem;
                        line-height: 1.875rem;
                        min-height: calc(1.875rem + (1px * 2))
                        }
                        a.combobox
                        {
                        display: none;
                        }
                        select:disabled
                        {
                        color: graytext;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!FollowUpEventFieldSet}" var="fieldValue">                     
                                <apex:inputField styleClass="slds-input" value="{!FollowUpEvent[fieldValue]}" rendered="{!IF(fieldValue.Type = 'textarea', true, false)}" required="{!OR(fieldValue.required, fieldValue.dbrequired)}"/>                                                        
                                <apex:inputField styleClass="combobox" value="{!FollowUpEvent[fieldValue]}" rendered="{!IF(fieldValue.Type = 'combobox', true, false)}" required="{!OR(fieldValue.required, fieldValue.dbrequired)}" type="text"/>

                            <!--</div>
                        </div>-->
                    </apex:repeat>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <br/>
                <apex:commandButton style="width: 100%;" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand" value="{!$Label.CreateFollowupCall}" action="{!save}" oncomplete="sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!newEventId}');" rerender="form" />

            </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Why not use the built-in SLDS we have now?

Comment: what makes you think slds is not working? that asides, sharing your code is always a +